# can I create XML file with sax library?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sax

I made XML file with sax library with Java.

```
StreamResult out = new StreamResult(new File("/home/aka/out.xml"));
```

but when I write like that on maven project and build the project as Jenkins plugin,
I think it cannot store xml file as I expected.
I searched web sites, most people use like `tranformer.transform(source, out)`
But, the source type is for DOM. I use Sax library.
Is there any other way?
please let me know

Comment: If it works locally it will also work as a Jenkins plugin - with one exception: locally you might have a directory "/home/aka" that doesn't exist on the jenkins server. If the directory doesn't exist you will get an `IOException`.

Comment: really...? actually when I run on my local, I used java project not maven. and I changed the directory path, but when I build jenkins using my plugin, it never stops..

Answer (score 0):

What you could try: Store the output data in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and only save it into a file after all processing has been completed:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StreamResult out = new StreamResult(os);

    // do the xml processing

    System.out.println("XML processing done, saving");
    Files.write(Paths.get("/home/aka/out.xml"), os.toByteArray());
    System.out.println("XML saved");
```

Including the two `System.out.println()` statements will help in finding out where the code gets stuck.